# Specify second default argument Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I have a function with three arguments, 2 of them having a default value:

```
function f(a, b=2, c=3){
    console.log(a, b, c)
}
```

If I'm perfectly happy with `b`'s value, **is there a way to call `f` and specify a value for `c` directly**?

In Python I'd do something like `f(1, c=5)`?

Use cases: if I don't know `b`'s default value or if there are many more arguments it would be cumbersome not to be able to do such a thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is there a way to call `f` and specify a value for `c` directly?

No, JavaScript doesn't have that kind of named parameter.

You can call `f` using the default for `b` by giving `undefined`:

```
f(1, undefined, 5);
```

```js
function f(a, b = 2, c = 3){
    console.log(a, b, c)
}
f(1, undefined, 5);
```

Alternately, you can define `f` differently: Have it accept an object that it destructures into parameters, then call it with an object:

```js
function f({a, b = 2, c = 3}){
    console.log(a, b, c)
}
f({a: 1, c: 5});
```

If you want it to be valid to call it with no object (it's an error with the above), provide a default for the destructured parameter:

```
function f({a, b = 2, c = 3} = {}){
// -------------------------^^^^^
    console.log(a, b, c)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `function f({a, b: 2, c:3}){`?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar No this is correct. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2)

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar - No. The above is how you provide destructuring defaults.

Comment: ah, you're right. I was overwhelm with something else. in fact it's due to not clear with the question... btw, second answer gave me idea of the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could pass an object with named keys like so:

```js
    function f({a, b=2, c=3}){
        console.log(a, b, c)
    }
    
    f({b: 4})
```

Comment: This is even cooler if you already have a b variable defined. `f({b})`